# sum of a sequence of r.v. bounded in probability and a sequence of r.v. diverging to infinity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I'm a little stuck on a problem. Thanks in advance for any comment, help or suggestions. So first at all, I have this definitions:

A random variable $X$ is said to be **bounded in probability** if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $M:=M(\varepsilon)> 0$ such that $$\mathbb{P}\bigg[\ |X|\leq M\bigg]\geq 1-\varepsilon.$$

A sequence $\{X_n\}$ of r.v. is said to be **bounded in probability** if $\sup_n |X_n|$ is bounded in probability.

A sequence $\{X_n\}$ is said to diverge to $\infty$ in probability if for all $M>0$ and all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N:=N(M,\varepsilon)$ such that if $N\leq n$, then $$\mathbb{P}\bigg[|X_n|>M\bigg] >1-\varepsilon.$$

It ask me to show that if $\{X_n\}$ diverges to $\infty$ in probability and $\{Y_n\}$ is bounded in probability, then $\{X_n + Y_n\}$ diverges to $\infty$ in probability.

I tried to get somenthing using the given bounds for both probabilities. By hypothesis in terms of the variables in the problem I have:

For every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a $M_b := M_b(\varepsilon)$ such that,
$\ \ \mathbb{P}\bigg[\bigg|\sup_n\ |Y_n|\bigg| \leq M_b \bigg] \geq 1- \varepsilon.$

and, for every $\varepsilon>0$ and $M>0$, there there exists a $N_d := N_d(\varepsilon, M)$ such that if $N_d \leq n$, $$ \mathbb{P}\bigg[|X_n|> M \bigg] > 1- \varepsilon.$$

So, my attempt was: taking $\varepsilon >0$ and $M >0$, there exists respectly $M_b:= M_b(\varepsilon)$ and defining $M_d:=M+M_b$, there exists an $N_d:=N_d(\varepsilon, M_d)$, in such a way that if
$$\bigg|\sup_n |Y_n|\bigg| \geq M_a, \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} |X_n| > M_d,$$
I could get the desired inequality because for $N_d \geq n$
\begin{align*}
M &= M_d - M_b \leq M_d - \big|\sup_n|Y_n|\big| \leq M_d -|Y_n| < |X_n|-|Y_n| \leq |X_n + Y_n|,
\end{align*}
but I don't know how to express this in terms of the given probabilities, being that the last inequality is the one I want to get the probability of and show that it is greater than $1-\varepsilon$ in order of conclude. Again, any help or idea is welcome, Thanks.

Comment: You have got the definitions wrong. According to your  definitions $(X_n)$ is bounded in probability iff $\sup |X_n| <\infty$ almost surely. These are very different from the usual definitions.

Comment: ok, thanks, I''m gonna check that

Comment: Hi, I already check the definition given in that question and it seems it's right as I set out above. I guess the idea is thinking bounded in probability in that way or sense.